# How to prevent calling constructor of one class while having access to its member functions in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, constructor, private

I have a class `A`, and a class `AStore`. My requirement is to prevent all other methods from initializing an instance of class `A`, which they should get an instance from `AStore`. In addition, I also need to access the member functions of `A` from the instance.

Factory pattern is not suitable for this problem as the constructor of `A` is still public. Ideally, it should throw compilation error when calling the constructor of class `A` while having access to its member functions.

Can I get C# solutions to this?

Comment: I think your only option is to make the constructor for `A` private and use reflection inside `AStore` to create an instance of `A`.

Comment: you can do this, but instead of a class `AStore`, you'd put a public static `CreateInstance` method and a private constructor  on `A`

Comment: "Factory pattern is not suitable for this problem as the constructor of A is still public" Why is it still public?

Comment: @JonHanna -- I don't think it matters whether it's `public` or `internal`, the point is he/she doesn't want other classes in the assembly to create instances (other than `AStore`).

Comment: @rory.ap if it wasn't public that would immediately prevent it as far as other assemblies go, so why is it still public?

Comment: @JonHanna -- I agree, but my point is, setting it to the most-restrictive access modifier (i.e. `internal`) which will still allow `AStore` to create an instance natively won't solve the problem where other classes in the assembly can create an instance too.

Comment: @Lin, is `A` a singleton?

Comment: If AStore is a singleton, you might consider merging it into A as static functions/data. Then make the A() constructor private.

Comment: @Nkosi, no it is not singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is moving `AStore` and `A` classes to the dedicated project and make constructor of `A` class internal.

```
// Project A
namespace ProjectA
{
    public class A
    {
        public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
        public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

        internal A() {}            
    }

    public class AStore
    {
        public A CreateA()
        {
            //internal constructor can be used
            return A();
        }
    }
}

// Project ConsumerOfA
namespace ConsumerOfA
{
    public static void UseA()
    {
        var store = new AStore();
        var instanceOfA = store.CreateA();

        // have access to the A's public members
    }
}
```

With this approach you will get perfect encapsulation you trying to achive.

Comment: This is the final approach we employ also. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

For restricting others to create an instance of class A you can use a private constructor and a static factory method to get the instance of that class.

```
public class A
{
  private A(){}

  public static A GetInstance()
  {
    return new A();
  }

  public void MemberFunctionOfA()
  {
  // blah blah...
  }
}
```

To enforce instance creation of A only via Astore you can use protected modifier and derive AStore from A. That way, only AStore will have access to its protected members like 'constructor' or 'factory method':

```
public class Astore : A
{
    public A GetInstanceOfA()
    {
        return base.GetInstance();
    }
}

public class A
{
    protected A() { }

    protected A GetInstance()
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public void MemberFunctionOfA()
    {
        // blah blah...
    }
}

//Usage
public class ConsumerClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var a = new A(); // Compile error
        a = new Astore().GetInstanceOfA();
        a.MemberFunctionOfA();
    }
}
```

But there're still chances that another class say 'UnWantedStore' can derive from A and serve instance of A.

Comment: I think approach with inheritance can be confusing for maintainers. For example why I need to create an A class if same logic can be accessed through AStore class?

Comment: Let's think of a consumer class exposing dependency on A. According to OP instantiation of A should only be allowed via AStore. and Consumer class won't accept AStore(Derived instance) so instance of A created via AStore can be injected. The proposed class is designed based on specific requirement provided by OP. It can be modified in many ways depends on requirement.

Comment: In my comment I tried to raise a question - will another developer understand OP's intents without multilines on comments?

Comment: Well, developers following SOLID principles will never come to such specific problem.. :)

Comment: Indeed, we cannot prevent others from inheriting class `A`. Thanks for your quick and nice suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

### Abstract classes to the rescue!

Indeed, there's yet another possible approach! I've never used it but it might work in your scenario. See the following code sample:

```
public abstract class A 
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string SayHello() => "hello world!";
}

public class AStore
{
     private class AInternal : A {}

     public void DoStuff()
     {
         A a = new AInternal();
         a.Text = "whatever";
         string helloText = a.SayHello();
     }
}
```

Let's explain the approach:

- Class `A` is abstract, therefore it can't be instantiated.
- Class `AStore` implements a `private` nested class called `AInternal` which just inherits `A` to let `AStore` members be able to instantiate `A`. Since `AInternal` is private, no other class than `AStore` can instantiate `AInternal`!
- Class `AStore` can access public `A` members because `AInternal` inherits `A`!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection too:

```
public class ClassA
{
    // The constructor(s) have to be private
    private ClassA() { }

    // Whatever other code you want
}

public class ClassB
{
    public static ClassA GetClassAInstance()
    {
        // Use reflection to get the private default constructor
        ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(ClassA).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { }, null);
        ClassA instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { }) as ClassA;

        return instance;
    }
}
```

You can find more information on the GetConstructor method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But anyone else can do the same thing.

Comment: @OldFart That's true no matter what solution you use - using private fields and variables doesn't really prevent people from accessing it if they really want to.

Comment: Then we need to remove "encapsulation" from the features of OO

Comment: @Fabio Not necessarily - it's just possible to bypass it.